# Show a gif when a device turns into landscape

Tags: css, html, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have a webpage where only mobile/tablet devices can access a page. I need to make it so that when the device turns into a landscape mode it will display a gif,
I have looked all over the internet and could not find anything that i could try.
how can i make a gif appear when a device turns into landscape?

P.S. thanks for all of the help in advance

Comment: _I have looked all over the internet and could not find anything that i could try..._ Now this is hard to believe.. not sure if you have asked google or not... sometimes you wont have the exact solution you are looking for... but its more like a puzzle.. different pieces... and for all pieces there are solutions around the internet

Comment: google "media queries orientation landscape"?

Comment: yeah, i will fix that, sorry first time actually posting on stack overflow, i am a programer/coder for 7 months now and i could not find this....

Comment: the thing is i whant to display a gif in full screen size on landscape mode